# Thread Safe implementation for In-Memory cache

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;
import java.net.URI;
import java.security.cert.CRLException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509CRL;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.naming.NamingException;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.kp.oppr.esb.logger.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class CachedCrlRepository {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = new Logger("CachedCrlRepository");

    private final Map<URI, SoftReference<X509CRL>> crlCache = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new HashMap<URI, SoftReference<X509CRL>>());;

    private static int DEFAULT_CACHE_AGING_HOURS;

    @Autowired
    private DgtlSgntrValidator validator;

    @Autowired
    private  CrlRepository crlRepository;

    public X509CRL findCrl(URI crlUri, X509Certificate issuerCertificate,
            Date validationDate) throws DigitalValdiationException,
            CertificateException, CRLException, IOException, NamingException {
        SoftReference<X509CRL> crlRef = this.crlCache.get(crlUri);
        if (null == crlRef) {
            LOGGER.info("Key CRL URI : " + crlUri +  "  not found in the cache " );
            return refreshCrl(crlUri, issuerCertificate, validationDate);
        }
        X509CRL crl = crlRef.get();
        if (null == crl) {
            LOGGER.info("CRL Entry garbage collected: " + crlUri);
            return refreshCrl(crlUri, issuerCertificate, validationDate);
        }
        if (validationDate.after(crl.getNextUpdate())) {
            LOGGER.info("CRL URI  no longer valid: " + crlUri);
            LOGGER.info("CRL validation date: " + validationDate + " is after CRL next update date: " + crl.getNextUpdate());
            return refreshCrl(crlUri, issuerCertificate, validationDate);
        }

        Date thisUpdate = crl.getThisUpdate();
        LOGGER.info("This update " + thisUpdate);

        /*
         * The PKI the nextUpdate CRL extension indicates 7 days. The
         * actual CRL refresh rate is every 3 hours. So it's a bit dangerous to
         * only base the CRL cache refresh strategy on the nextUpdate field as
         * indicated by the CRL.
         */

        DateTime cacheMaturityDateTime = new DateTime(thisUpdate)
                .plusHours(DEFAULT_CACHE_AGING_HOURS);
        LOGGER.info("Cache maturity Date Time " + cacheMaturityDateTime);
        if (validationDate.after(cacheMaturityDateTime.toDate())) {
            LOGGER.info("Validation date: "  + validationDate + " is after cache maturity date: " + cacheMaturityDateTime.toDate());
            return refreshCrl(crlUri, issuerCertificate, validationDate);
        }
        LOGGER.info("using cached CRL: " + crlUri);
        return crl;
    }

    public static int getDEFAULT_CACHE_AGING_HOURS() {
        return DEFAULT_CACHE_AGING_HOURS;
    }

    public static void setDEFAULT_CACHE_AGING_HOURS(int dEFAULT_CACHE_AGING_HOURS) {
        DEFAULT_CACHE_AGING_HOURS = dEFAULT_CACHE_AGING_HOURS;
    }

    private X509CRL refreshCrl(URI crlUri, X509Certificate issuerCertificate,
            Date validationDate) throws DigitalValdiationException,
            CertificateException, CRLException, IOException, NamingException {
        X509CRL crl = crlRepository.downloadCRL(crlUri.toString());
        this.crlCache.put(crlUri, new SoftReference<X509CRL>(crl));
        return crl;
    }




}
```

I have this class CachedCrlrepository that stores CRL list from particular provider. I want to know if my implementation is thread safe or I am missing something over here. The cache is for a web service, so it is multi-threaded.

My doubt in for this particular method

```
private X509CRL refreshCrl(URI crlUri, X509Certificate issuerCertificate,
                Date validationDate) throws DigitalValdiationException,
                CertificateException, CRLException, IOException, NamingException {
            X509CRL crl = crlRepository.downloadCRL(crlUri.toString());
            this.crlCache.put(crlUri, new SoftReference<X509CRL>(crl));
            return crl;
        }
```

I think this particular line need to be synchronized

```
this.crlCache.put(crlUri, new SoftReference<X509CRL>(crl));

 synchronized(this)
{
this.crlCache.put(crlUri, new SoftReference<X509CRL>(crl));

}
```

Another issue which I see is that after a GC is run the cache still have that entry in the memory. It never execute these line of code

```
if (null == crl) {
            LOGGER.info("CRL Entry garbage collected: " + crlUri);
            return refreshCrl(crlUri, issuerCertificate, validationDate);
        }
```

Comment: Am actually confused, do you want it to be thread-safe or not

Comment: Consider using a library like [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Cache) instead.

Comment: Re. `put()`: no, the call to `Collections.synchronizedMap()` does that for you.  I don't like the use of `SoftReference` though, it's not really good practice.

Comment: I don't believe that it is possible to answer this question in an authoritative and correct way.  The answer to the question "is this thread safe" necessarily must depend on the thread safety policy that has been established for a class or classes and whether the use of instances of those classes violates that policy.  Since you don't articulate the policies, there's no way to know.  At the end of the day, thread safety is only about protecting mutable state ... and there are a variety of ways to that goal (and a variety of ways to make missteps).

Comment: @Saurabh Jhunjhunwala -- Want it to be thread safe

Comment: @scottb-- This class is declared as singleton in Spring bean configuration.However, the classes using this bean is of prototype. Since this is a cache I want to have a single instance of this bean , shared among  multiple classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally you should not use a synchronized Map in cases where you are expecting heavy traffic and high concurrent access on your object which in this case is `crlCache`. For each and every read or write threads will wait behind another and in heavy load, your thread count will go high and eventually your server will crash. You can look into [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). which is designed to work efficiently in such scenarios.

Your second point:

```
synchronized(this)
{
this.crlCache.put(crlUri, new SoftReference<X509CRL>(crl));

}
```

is not at all required with current code as `put` method is already synchronized.

For minimal changes replace

```
private final Map<URI, SoftReference<X509CRL>> crlCache = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new HashMap<URI, SoftReference<X509CRL>>());;
```

with

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<URI, SoftReference<X509CRL>> crlCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<URI, SoftReference<X509CRL>>();
```

Finally, using [SoftReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html) is good but there are better options. [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) from google is a very robust and efficient cache builder.

Comment: Well, not "must" but I agree `ConcurrentHashMap` is probably a better choice if there's any chance of high demand/threads.

Comment: "First of all don't use a synchronized Map for a multi threaded environment as they cause terrible performance issues."  Of course, this is bad advice.  Synchronized collections are perfectly acceptable solutions for any situation in which contention will be low.  Serialization of object state accesses is expected to harm performance only in those situations in which concurrent access is high thereby producing high contention.  Moreover, the requirement for atomicity in situations for which concurrent access is not available makes synchronization a simple and, often, clean first-pass solution.

Comment: @scottb: Thanks for the advice, made edits accordingly to put a more modest statement.